# What's the phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a phrase for 'split allegiances.' Split rule, indecisive loyalty, multiple beckonings, etc.

The context is Thomas Becket in Eliot's work 'Murder in the Cathedral.'

Becket is quite unsure over his allegiance to King Henry or the Church, and he does not resolve his '...' until he is appointed Archbishop and can truly discover his passion and love for the Church.

Dilemma isn't really what I'm going for. I am looking more for something that describes the anguish he felt from his allegiances to two highly valued positions (Archbishop and Chancellor of England).

Comment: "Divided loyalties" is a common phrase, but it implies a less-than-100% commitment to either side.

Comment: Or 'conflict of conscience'; seeing as it's Thomas Becket.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it slightly as it sounds as though Becket is feeling *[torn](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/torn)*.

> Becket is torn over his allegiance to King Henry or the Church, and he does not resolve this until he is appointed Archbishop and can truly discover his passion and love for the Church.